# Pulled my docker django project but don't run

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose

I create a dockerized version of my Django project in this fashion:

create my Dockerfile
create my docker-compose.yml
create my .dockerignore

on my machine all done, if i run `docker-compose up` all start.
Then i build the project

```
docker-compose build .
```

and push to my hub repo

```
docker push myrepo/myproject
```

well, at this point i connect from another machine and i do:

```
docker pull myrepo/myproject
```

as you can see it download the image:

[image]

but when i run it nothing appen:

```
docker run d080812784c6
```

[image]

in my docker-compose file, into my web service i specify the command:

```
command: python /Code/core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

...how can i start my pulled docker image correctly?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: on other machine, do you use docker compose?

Comment: yes but if i run docker-compose up i get: ERROR: Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent. Are you in the right directory?

Comment: Instead of pulling docker images, you should copy the docker-compose.yml file to your other machine and run docker-compose up commands

Comment: yes but i would to distribute public my image, i need a command for pull and run for everyone easily

Comment: probably that would not be possible if you are using docker-compose(or maybe I don't know much about distributing it). If you are using docker compose, better to distribute the compose file, else you should write a single docker file and push it to repo, then distribute it

Answer (score 1):

Instruction mentioned on docker-compose.yml file will not be considered when you run

```
docker run d080812784c6
```

You can run your application with docker or with help of docker-compose.

Instruction to run on  docker-compose.yml.

```
docker-compose up
```

This will take `command:` mentioned in the docker-compose.yml

To run your application with docker alone, you need to add ENTRYPOINT or CMD instruction at docker file.

Add `ENTRYPOINT python /Code/core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` in your Docker file and run  `docker run d080812784c6` and expose the port `EXPOSE 8080`

Answer (score 0):

First run this command:
`docker ps --all`

This will list all the containers, Exited or Running.
If there was a Exited container then you probably have some errors in your container. Try `docker logs -f containerId` to see what's the problem.